# After update and reinstall solution, SharePoint keeps reference to 14 hive

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2013

I have updated SharePoint from 2010 to 2013.
We build our solutions for 2013. 
One of them has master pages.
When we removed the old solution and install new one, some pages complains about not existing master page. When I manually copied this master pages to the 14 hive under proper feature folder (i recreated this manually), page stops complaining.

Looks like SharePoint keeps reference to this master page from 14 hive.
This is my elemets.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Module Name="MasterPage" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
      <File Path="MasterPage\Intranet.master" Url="Intranet.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" ReplaceContent="True" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="True" />    
      <File Path="MasterPage\Application.master" Url="Application.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" ReplaceContent="True" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="True"/>    
   </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the masterpage gallery (you can access to this menu in your site settings), the value of your masterpage have to be set to 15 for the "column compatible ui version".

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing, but I forgot I have to disable and enable the feature with master pages again.